# I am getting error in ADFS SSO in asp.net webforms application using OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, adfs

I have created a sample webforms application with below code in startup.cs:

```
   private static string adfsRealm = 
   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static string adfsMetadata = 
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];
    private static string adfsWreply = 
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wreply"];
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
   app.Properties 
  ["Microsoft.Owin.Security.Constants.DefaultSignInAsAuthenticatio 
    nType"] = "ExternalCookie";
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new 
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
            AuthenticationMode = 
    Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive
        });
        var testADFS = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
            // AuthenticationType = "Antariksh ADFS",
            //Caption = "Antariksh Domain",
            //localhost
            Wreply = adfsWreply,
            Wtrealm = adfsRealm
        };
        //add to pipeline
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(testADFS);
    }
```

and below code in default.aspx:

```
   if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)

        {

            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "~/" },
            WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        }
```

when I run the application it is redirecting to the login page with below error, Please let me know what might be the issue:

```
  An error occurred
 An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information.
 Error details
  Activity ID: a1f3f98b-4d35-4cf9-4600-00800100003a
 Error time: Wed, 11 Sep 2019 05:50:48 GMT
 Cookie: enabled
 User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: You need to look in the ADFS event log.

Comment: Yes, there was a problem in the configuration. It's fixed and now any request coming to my application is being redirected to the adfs login, but once login its redirected back to the default.aspx page and giving this error: "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed" I update code in default.aspx, instead of "~/" in redirecturi mentioned in the question, I added redirecturi="default.aspx". what might be wrong in the code?

Comment: Have a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/. It's for Azure AD but the code is similar.